# How to counteract Doppler's effect?

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect

I am working on a robot in which I am detecting obstacles on sides using Ultrasonic transducers. Now the problem is, the target speed for the robot is 8.5 m/s and at this speed, the doppler's effect might make the judgments for the robot invalid, as by the time it registers a reading, the robot will move from its postion.

To counteract this affect, I came up with this alignment for the sensors.

[image]

The sonar also has a finite max distance, beyond which the signal strength becomes too low for an echo to register, even with a perfect surface to bounce off.  Driving outdoors, or on a big open area indoors, navigating between cones, most of the readings will not give an echo, and will thus delay the program execution by one second.

So the lane in which in I have to run is 3m wide. So if I'm in between, each sensor has to detect cones within 1.5m range, at the speed of sound and in the meanwhile my robot moves about 9cm.

So can the design I've come up with counteract this problem. If not then how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: The Doppler effect is the change of the *frequency* of the sound, not just some general delay of the signals. The sound moves at a finite speed so if you rely on it, you won't be able to get rid of the delay. You may switch to lasers because the speed of light is much higher.

Comment: @LubošMotl can you suggest some??

Comment: Suggest some lasers? No, I am not an expert - not even remotely - in any of these things. I just meant that if you managed to replace sound by light, delays would shrink considerably. Sound simply isn't too fast and isn't too efficient in transmitting too much information. You may at most speed up - perhaps - the detection of a signal from some number of waves etc. But the very propagation of the sound does take some time.

Comment: I think http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: This is really an engineering problem, but you are really fighting a good property of the system rather than to use it to your advantage. The Doppler shift in your signals tells you if the objects it detects are moving or not. The delay in the signal is simply something you have to learn to compensate for. If the cones are 1.5m away, you will have an approx. 10ms delay. If your robot moves 9cm in that time, it's going at 9m/s? Are you sure about that? :-)

Comment: Maybe use infrared LEDs as a substitute, like the tv remote control?

Comment: @philip_0008 I have to run the robot in bright sunlight... Won't infrared get distorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Lubos Motl that your concern really seems to be the time delay between emission and detection (which depends on distance), rather than the Doppler Effect (change in frequency, which depends on relative speed between observer and object).

As Lubos Motl suggests, using light instead of sound would solve your problems. The transit time is much shorter (because the speed of light is a million times faster than the speed of sound in air), the range will be much longer (because light can be focussed into a narrower cone, and it can be distinguished from background noise more easily), and the times to emit/detect light are much shorter (because this is all done electronically, there are no slow mechanical parts as there are with sound).

Either you can build your own range-finder using infrared LEDs, or you can buy a readymade system, such as the Sharp GP2D120 mentioned in the following artcile :

http://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-Infrared-Rangefinder-Similar-to-Sharp-GP/

I agree with CuriousOne and Mainz that this is really an engineering problem, and you would get better help from Robotics SE or Engineering SE.

Comment: Actually I thought it would be a doppler's effect issue that's why I asked. What you guys tell me about doppler's is entirely different from what I am being taught in school. Anyways, doubt about IR ism whether or not it will be affected by sunlight

Comment: Yes, IR detection may be affected by sunlight.  However, as the article shows, you can make the LED emit pulses of IR light, which can be distinguished from the continuous IR from the sun.

Comment: What if I use this - http://robokits.co.in/sensors/sharp-ir-rangefinder-gp2y0a710k0f-100cm-to-550cm

Comment: @YaddyVirus doppler is very negligible at low speeds, unless you want to detect pulsating signals

Comment: @YaddyVirus : Sorry, like Lubos Motl I am not an expert in electronics or robotics technology.  I recommend that you post your question on the Robotics SE website.

Comment: @philip_0008 well I thought the same, until I tested it out today, my robot went from a robot to a wreck all bcz the sensor was too slow to detect. Anyways thanks for all the help

Comment: @YaddyVirus : re your comment to philip_0008, you still do not seem to see the difference between the time delay between emission and detection, and the change in the frequency between emission and detection.  The Doppler Effect is the latter.  The former is the cause of your wrecked robot.  If you want to keep using ultrasound you probably have to either (a) reduce the speed of your robot. or (b) increase the range of the detector - MaxBotix Inc sells sensors with ranges of 10m or more : http://www.maxbotix.com/Ultrasonic_Sensors/MB1010.htm.

Comment: @sammygerbil schoolboy here, a bit of confusion, now solved. Umm uh I tried increasing the range of my sensor, kind of worked, but again not a reliable solution.